# Nginx - Enabling Browser Caching

Tags: nginx, browser-cache

I'm no expert on this subject and the server isn't managed by myself but I've tried to setup W3 Total Cache on a WordPress site which is running via Nginx.

W3 Total Cache has created an nginx.conf file in the following location:

/var/www/domain.com/public/nginx.conf

Nginx has been restarted but the browser caching rules don't seem to be applying.

Can anyone shed any light on why this isn't working or what I'd need to look for?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions or need further clarification on anything, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that you checked in the chrome dev tools for `disable cache` option?

Comment: Thanks for the question/comment. I don't think this is the issue though - GT Metrix is reporting that browser caching is not active on the server.